# What exactly does this | separator do?

Tags: objective-c

I'm working on a group project and am working some clean up on deprecated code.  One line I came across was as follows:

```
NSDateComponents *components = [appSharedData.calendar components:NSDayCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSYearCalendarUnit fromDate:firstDate toDate:secondDate options:0];
```

This may be a bit of a silly question, but what exactly does the | separator mean/do?

Also, as a quick disclaimer, I know that's not the cause for the deprecation warning.  I've just seen the separator on occasion over my roughly one and a half years of coding but never completely understood what it was doing.

Comment: That's the C "bitwise OR" operator.

Comment: Awesome, thank you!  This sent me in the right direction and lead me to find this link with more details: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/10/bitwise-operators/.
This is my first time asking a question (that received an answer) on here.  Do you need to repost your comment as an "answer" so I can accept it?  
Thanks again.